# Datatables Package for Laravel 5 with Parse as data source

Tags: php, parse-platform, datatables, laravel-5

I am using Laravel 5, [Datatables jQuery plugin](http://www.datatables.net/) and [Datatables package](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle) for handling the server side requests.

Everything works great if I use Eloquent. The problem is my application needs to get the data from [Parse.com](https://parse.com/) using it's PHP SDK. Is there a way to make the Datatables package work if I pass to it's `of` method an array that contains the data I need to display?

a working example is:

```
$users = User::select(['name','email']);
return Datatables::of($users)->make();
```

what I would need would be:

```
$users = array(['name' => 'John Doe', 'email' => 'john@email.com'], 
               ['name' => 'Robert Roe', 'email' => 'robert@email.com']);

return Datatables::of($users)->make();
```

Comment: Try passing `Datatables::of` instances of your `User` class instead of arrays.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but as long as I use Parse's PHP SDK there is no User class to pass to the `Datatables::of()` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of v5.x of [Datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle) package, It is now possible to pass a Collection as a data source.

```
$data = array(['name' => 'John Doe', 'email' => 'john@email.com'], 
               ['name' => 'Robert Roe', 'email' => 'robert@email.com']);
$users = new Collection($data);

return Datatables::of($users)->make();
```

Comment: removing ->get() from table query will also result the same