# Laravel Datatables empty collection error

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, datatables

I'm using [Laravel Datatables](https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables) package to show Ajaxified tables.

I'm getting an error when the collection i want to show in my table is empty, the error is:

> ErrorException in CollectionEngine.php line 46: array_keys() expects
>   parameter 1 to be array, null given

My controller contains two simple functions

```
// get the view
public function getItems() {
  return view('someview');
}

// get data for datatables
public function getItemsdata() {
  $data = DataModel::all();
  return Datatables::of($data)->make(true);
}
```

When `$data` is not empty, everything works just fine but if it is empty, I get the error! how can i fix this? any ideas?

Comment: What's the version of your laravel?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the `isEmpty()` function of laravel

```
  public function getItemsdata() {
   $data = DataModel::all();
   if($data->isEmpty()){ //I think laravel has isEmpty() function
     return 'error!'; //throw exception here
   }else{
     return Datatables::of($data)->make(true);
   }
 }
```

Comment: well no this won't solve it because this will cause an error in the front-side (Datatables JS) and it will display an alert with the exception error message.

Comment: Can you display the returned data of `$data` when it's empty?

Comment: your answer will certainly solve the php error (i've done it before posting) but the javascript error remains even if i return an empty array(json) because it expects some keys in the json response

Comment: Maybe it needs an array. I think this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30000555/datatables-package-for-laravel-5-with-parse-as-data-source